# Dropdown menu does not select model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create task model that has many required courses. But when I create a task, the dropdown menu does not attach any courses to it. (As in Task.first.courses returns nil and the course_id attribute is also nil).

Task Controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_company!, only: [:create, :destroy]
def create
  @courses = Course.all
  @task = current_company.tasks.build(task_params)
  if @task.save
    flash[:success] = "Task created!"
    redirect_to @task
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def new
  @courses = Course.all
  @task = Task.new
end

private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description, files: [])
  end
```

Course Model:

```
belongs_to :task, optional: true
```

Task Model:

```
has_many :courses
```

Add_task_id_to_courses Migration:

```
def change
  add_column :courses, :task_id, :integer
end
```

Add_course_id_to_tasks Migration:

```
def change
  add_column :tasks, :course_id, :integer
end
```

Tasks/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :name, placeholder: "Task Name" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Add Description" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :files, multiple: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_select :course_ids, @courses, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true} %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Course `belongs_to :task`, Task `has_many :courses`. It means that you need only `task_id` in courses table. Remove `course_id` from tasks table. `course_ids` is a method, [generated](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) from `has_many` association, not a column name.

But it is not the cause of the issue. You forgot to add `course_ids` to permitted params.

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description, files: [], course_ids: [])
end
```

Don't forget to check server logs when something goes wrong. Now you should see there something like `Unpermitted parameters: course_ids`